# GitVersion config not working on main branch

Tags: git, continuous-deployment, gitversion

I am using a gitversion for automatic versioning and it is working like a charm. I am using it for a nuget package and the develop creates a package with alpha tag and release branches create packages with beta tags. Problem occurs when I merge a PR to main - it always chooses 0.1.0 as a version. Probably just some setting in the config.. I am posting the config below, cheers !

```
mode: ContinuousDelivery 
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: '' # ci
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
branches:
  main:
    regex: ^master$|^main$
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - release
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: true
  develop:
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: alpha
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tracks-release-branches: true
  release:
    regex: ^release?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: None
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - release
    is-release-branch: true
  feature:
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - release
    - feature
    - hotfix
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: '' # PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)'
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    - release
    - feature
    - hotfix
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
  hotfix:
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    source-branches:
    - develop
    - main
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
    is-mainline: false
ignore:
  sha: []
commit-date-format: yyyy-MM-dd
merge-message-formats: {}
update-build-number: true
```